# ReactSearchAutocomplete DO NOT select the first option when writing

Tags: reactjs, search

I use this code https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-sun-f73pn9?file=/src/App.js
in my project and it becomes different from what appears.
When I write in the search box the first option is not selected.
where when I use it in my project the first option is always selected.
Same here: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-kate-7k3xo7?file=/src/serviceWorker.js

Please if u know the reason help me with that.
How I can do not select the first option always like the first code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: the code appear on code sandbox actually (the links)